# Best way to store multi-values in a field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form field that accepts multiple values (Number values between 00-999) that I want to store inside a MySQL field.

**What is the best option to go with? (Field type?)**

I want to store the data in this format,

```
1|2|3|4|5|
```

I want to later query those values and be able to separate them from each other with PHP for mathematical operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not good idea to store values using glues like commas and pipes. Because later when you need to execute sql and to some mathematical operation , it will be tedious. IMO seperate bridge table will do the task

tables

forms

```
id, name
```

form_values

```
form_id value
1        1
1        2
1        3
```

you can use `group_concat` to fetch value as your output and can have calculations easiliy.

Comment: And even still if OP wants to insert `1|2|3|4|5|` then obvious choice are char or text :)